# WPF custom control constructor throws io exception only after clean - rebuild - run

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012

We are using some custom controls in .NET 4.5 version of WPF.

The issue appears only when we clean, rebuild and run the application. If we just clean and run the application it works correctly. The controls are in the same project as the main application.

We get the following io exception in the InitializeComponent method of the control:

```
"Cannot locate resource 'controls/customcontrol.xaml'"
```

Stack trace:

```
at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at namespace.controls.customcontrol.InitializeComponent()
at namespace.controls.customcontrol..ctor()
```

The issue is occuring in both 2012 and 2013 versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem in `customcontrol`. How was it made? By using `VS` (mayhap by previous version?) or somehow *manually*? You could try to fix it by specifying full url `"/SolutionName;component/controls/customcontrol.xaml"` somewhere in `InitializeComponent()` I think. Other option is to create it again normally and just copy/paste `xaml` and code.

Comment: check in your configuration manager that all required projects are set to be built.

Comment: +1 I also have this problem for one particular control, but I couldn't find anything wrong with it either... it works exactly as expected except for this warning and I never had any warnings in previous versions of Visual Studio.